# Permission denied error when compiling fortran code in Netbeans 7.3.1 on ubuntu linux 12.04.2

Tags: permissions, executable, netbeans, fortran

So I read through a bunch of posting about similar issues, but none of them seemed to fix this problem. I am running netbeans 7.3.1 on ubuntu 12.04.2 x64. I wrote some fortran code and saved it to an ext4 internal drive that I have. However, when I try and run the code through netbeans or even from the console, I tend to get a permission denied error. But, when I save and compile the code in my home directory, it seems to run just fine.

Now as a pre-empt to the common issues. the partition that is having the trouble is an ext4 partition, so it is not a FAT or NTFS partition where I cannot run executables from Ubuntu. Second, the drive is set for permission to run executables. I mount the drive through pysdm and the run binaries flag is enabled. I am not sure how to check the drive settings though.

I am including some samples of the console output when I compile the file and when the execution error comes up.

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/media/jaimini/workspace/netbeans/Hello_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hello_1  
make[2]: Entering directory `/media/jaimini/workspace/netbeans/Hello_1'
make[2]: `dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hello_1' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/jaimini/workspace/netbeans/Hello_1'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/jaimini/workspace/netbeans/Hello_1'
```

Here is the run attempt:

```
/bin/sh: 1: exec: /media/jaimini/workspace/netbeans/Hello_1/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hello_1:
Permission denied

RUN FINISHED; exit value 126; real time: 0ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
```

Any suggestions. This is really messing up my workflow. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check if `/media/jaimini/workspace/netbeans/Hello_1/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hello_1` has execute permission?

Comment: The permissions on the file are set for execute. See the output below.
    -rwxrwxr-x 1 krishnab krishnab 10507 Jun 19 18:31 hello_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for a script to be executed, apart from script's execute permission, all the parent directories of that script from the root (/) should have execute permission. See below for an example.

```
~$ ls -ltrh | grep Temp
dr-xr-xr-x  2 thefourtheye thefourtheye 4.0K Jun 20 08:53 Temp

~$ chmod 666 Temp

~$ ls -ltrh | grep Temp
drw-rw-rw-  2 thefourtheye thefourtheye 4.0K Jun 20 08:53 Temp

~$ Temp/TestIP.sh
bash: Temp/TestIP.sh: Permission denied

~$ chmod 755 Temp

~$ ls -ltrh | grep Temp
drwxr-xr-x  2 thefourtheye thefourtheye 4.0K Jun 20 08:53 Temp

~$ Temp/TestIP.sh
Your IP Address   : 10.0.2.15
Your N/W Mask     : 255.255.255.0
Your N/W Address  : 10 0 2 0
IPs to be Checked : 4060477953
^C
```